# Is It possible to perform serialization with circular references?

Tags: c#, serialization, circular-reference

So, my entity class (written in C#) follows a parent child model where every child object must have a Parent property in which it keeps reference of its Parent.

This Parent property causes issues in serialization of the Object due to circular references.

I can't remove the reference to parent, neither I can mark it XmlIgnore (since I need to read it back when I deserialize the XML)

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XML serialization doesn't support circular references, you need to exclude the parent property from the serialization using the `XmlIgnore` attribute. See [this blog post](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/06/12/c-parentchild-relationship-and-xml-serialization/) for a way to maintain the relationship when you deserialize.

Alternatively, you could use `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`. It supports circular references, but doesn't provide much control over the XML schema...

Comment: nice blog post. trying your example.

Comment: Thanks Thomos, your solution was life saver!

Answer (score 11):

You can either create your own `XMLSerializer` or use the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) and the `[DataContract(`[`IsReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference.aspx)`= true)]` attribute to tell the serializer to remember the references.

Comment: Thanks for response, any example with a piece of code will add more help. :)