# Error while XML serializing an object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I thought my class conformed to all the XML serialization requirements. Here is part of the error message.

InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type TheseusAndTheMinotaur.LevelDesigner.ModelMap.
       Source=System.Xml
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteStartElement(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean writePrefixed, XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterModelMap.Write4_ModelMap(String n, String ns, ModelMap o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterModelMap.Write3_Cell(String n, String ns, Cell o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterModelMap.Write4_ModelMap(String n, String ns, ModelMap o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterModelMap.Write5_ModelMap(Object o)
       InnerException:

Is this the error?: Message=A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type TheseusAndTheMinotaur.LevelDesigner.ModelMap. In my data model which I can post here if you like, I have a map that has a list of cells, and each cell knows "myMap" of type Map. Is this causing some circular error (looping)?

I have not added any attributes to my code, as I am aware if it conforms to the XML serialization requirements i do not need to?

Data Model:

```
    public class ModelMap
    {
        public ModelMap()
        {
        }

        public int rows { get; set; }
        public int cols { get; set; }
        public int boardXPos { get; set; }
        public int boardYPos { get; set; }
        public int myCellSize { get; set; }
        public string HorizontalWallSource { get; set; }
        public string VerticalWallSource { get; set; }
        public string cellBgSource { get; set; }
        public string theseusSource { get; set; }
        public string minotaurSource { get; set; }
        public string exitSource { get; set; }
        public int myWidth { get; set; }
        public int myHeight { get; set; }
        private List<Cell> m_cells = new List<Cell>();
        public List<Cell> myCells
        {
            get
            {
                return m_cells;
            }
            set
            {
                m_cells = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cell Class:

```
    public class Cell
    {
        public Cell()
        {
        }

        public ModelMap myMap { get; set; }
        public bool hasMinotaur { get; set; }
        public bool hasTheseus { get; set; }
        public bool isExit { get; set; }
        public int mySize { get; set; }
        public CellSide myRightWall { get; set; }
        public CellSide myBottomWall { get; set; }
        public int myColumn { get; set; }
        public int myRow { get; set; }
    }

    public class CellSide
    {
        public CellSide()
        {
            this.hasWall = 0;
            this.isHighlighted = false;
        }

        public bool isHighlighted { get; set; }
        public int hasWall { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My serialisation code:

```
private void btnSaveMap_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new
    XmlSerializer(typeof(ModelMap));

    ModelMap map = this.myMapController.myMap;

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\xml\test.xml"))
    {
        mySerializer.Serialize(writer, map);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: "my data model which I can post here if you like" - we like...

Comment: XMLSerializer does not play well with circular references.  You might need to use `SoapFormatter` instead.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks, I have posted the data model :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a circular reference like this:

`ModelMap.myCells` -> (traverse `List<Cell>`) -> `Cell.myMap` -> `ModelMap`

where both `ModelMap`s refer to the same instance, so serializing would loop forever.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004495/1399567) explains your situation well, and explains a couple of solutions.

If you do a Ctrl-F on "circular" on this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can see a common XML structure for supporting repeated object instances using `id` and `ref` attributes on XML elements; this is crucial for deserialization of the file back into the same object graph.

Comment: Thanks! I have already used BinaryFormatter to serialize, and it seems to have worked. However i will also look into this solution